# playframework 2.2 functional test

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.2

I updated playframework(Java version) to version 2.2. There were some major changes to way the webservice is called. In the versions before 2.2 they were called like this:

```
@Test
public void testInServer() {
running(testServer(3333), new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
     assertThat(
       WS.url("http://localhost:3333").get().get().getStatus()
     ).isEqualTo(OK);
  }
});
}
```

With the changes in the new version the get() method to access the result is deprecated. I think the new function call indicates a timeout. Is this the right way to get access? Is there an other way to write the functional test? How long should the timeout should be?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm essentially using it pretty much the same way on play 2.2.1

```
@Test
public void testServerOK() {
  running(testServer(3333), new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         //Context.current.set(ctx);
         WSRequestHolder wsreqHolder = WS.url("http://localhost:3333");
         F.Promise<WS.Response> promiseOfResult = wsreqHolder.get();
         assertThat(
           promiseOfResult.get().getStatus()
         ).isEqualTo(OK);
      }
   });
}
```

Keep in mind that `wsreqHolder.get();`  returns a `Promise`

Comment: BTW, `F.Promise.get();` is deprecated. Use `.get(long, TimeUnit)` or `.get(long)` instead.